# resize read-only typed array

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, typed-arrays

I have created my own class that extends the `ImageData` class to give me more methods to manipulate and construct image data:

```
class ImageAsset extends ImageData {
    constructor(data, width, height) {
        super(data, width, height);
    }
    static fromCanvas(canvas) {
        if(canvas instanceof HTMLCanvasElement) {
            var image = canvas.getContext("2d").getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            return new ImageAsset(image.data, image.width, image.height);
        }
        else return null;
    }
    static fromFile(file) {

    }
    static fromImage(image) {
        if(image instanceof HTMLImageElement) {
            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            canvas.width = image.width;
            canvas.height = image.height;
            canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(image, 0, 0);
            return this.fromCanvas(canvas);
        } else return null;
    }
    get canvas() {
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = this.width;
        canvas.height = this.height;
        canvas.getContext("2d").putImageData(this, 0, 0);
        return canvas;
    }
    get image() {
        var image = document.createElement("img");
        image.src = this.file;
        return image;
    }
    get file() {
        return this.canvas.toDataURL();
    }
    resize(width, height) {
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
        context.drawImage(this.canvas, 0, 0, width, height);

        return ImageAsset.fromCanvas(canvas);
    }
    recolor(colors) {
        var compressor = new RgbQuant({colors: colors});
        compressor.sample(this);
        this.data.set(compressor.reduce(this));
    }

}
```

Notice how the method `recolor` changes the values inside the `data` property, which is `Uint8ClampedArray` protected as read-only by the superclass, using the method `set`. This is the ideal behavior.

However, the method `resize` returns a new instance of my object because `data` cannot be overwritten (read-only) or resized (typed-array). This is unfavorable.

How can I make the method `resize` set the instance of the caller to have new `data`, `width`, and `height` values, all of which are protected as read-only by the superclass?

Comment: I did want to note I am using the following library for color space compression: https://github.com/leeoniya/RgbQuant.js/tree/master

Answer (score 0):

You can set `data`, `height`, `width` to `this` and use in `resize` function

```
constructor(data, width, height) {
    super(data, width, height);

    this.data = data;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
}


resize() {
    console.log(this.data, this.width, this.height);
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: caught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'data' of object '#<ImageAsset>'

Comment: Maybe you can try with `this.childData = data`?

Comment: I could rename the properties in my own class, but then the benefit of extending my class over `ImageData` (inheriting the prototype methods) would be lost.

Comment: So you can create function to get data in your parent class. Ex: getData return this.data

Comment: Curious as to what benefits you think you get from extending `ImageData`. Wouldn't it make more sense to create a type that manages an internal imagedata?

Comment: So you want to protect data from parent and you want to get from child class?

Comment: How can you get the variable when you don't want to export this?

Comment: I could just add a method `get imageData` and have the class extend the standard Object superclass.